# Woocommerce: delivery method change event handler not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

My HTML code (delivery methods list of radio buttons) is:

```
<ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup8" value="local_pickup:8" class="shipping_method" checked="checked"><label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup8">Local pickup</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_edostavka-package-door-stock7138" value="edostavka-package-door-stock:7:138" class="shipping_method"><label for="shipping_method_0_edostavka-package-door-stock7138">Postamat: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">265&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1" value="flat_rate:1" class="shipping_method"><label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1">Courier delivery <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">350&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It cannot changed (Woocommerce HTML generation). At least I do not want to change it.

My task is add Javascript handlers on selection change event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    let methods = jQuery('.shipping_method’);
    methods.each(function(index) {
        $(this).bind('change', function() {
            alert('Change event fired for ' + this.val());
        });
    });
});
```

Handlers are not fired when delivery method (radio button with class == ’shipping_method’) changed.

Change handler for whole list of radio also doesn’t work:

```
methods.bind('change', function() {
    alert(this.val());
});
```

What’s wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in your JS you're using the wrong type of apostrophe, `’` instead of `'`, which is unsupported in JS, to close the jQuery selector string.

```
let methods = jQuery('.shipping_method’); // change the last apostrophe on this line
```

Secondly, in the `change` event handler `this` refers to the Element object which has no `val()` method. You need to call it on a jQuery object, so use `$(this).val()` instead.

Lastly, `bind()` is deprecated and should not be used. Use `on()` instead, and make sure you're using an up to date version of jQuery, ideally at least something 3.x. You also don't need the `each()` loop, as you can bind event handlers to a collection of Elements in a single jQuery object. Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.shipping_method').on('change', function() {
    console.log('Change event fired for ' + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup8" value="local_pickup:8" class="shipping_method" checked="checked"><label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup8">Local pickup</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_edostavka-package-door-stock7138" value="edostavka-package-door-stock:7:138" class="shipping_method"><label for="shipping_method_0_edostavka-package-door-stock7138">Postamat: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">265&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1" value="flat_rate:1" class="shipping_method"><label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate1">Courier delivery <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">350&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₽</span></span></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's worth noting that both of these issues were visible in the console, which is where you should look first when trying to debug JS logic.

Comment: This code works great in general case. But for case of Woocommerce checkout page these handlers not fired :-(.
For sure code is reachable

Comment: How are the elements added to the DOM? If they are appended after document.ready fires, use delegated event handlers: `$(document).on('change', '.shipping_method', function() { ...`

Answer (score 1):

@Rory: Awesome! Yes, your advice works great!

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know there's a way to get which shipping method is clicked using a WooCommerce hook:

```
 function prefix_detect_chosen_shipping_method(){
    
            if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ){
                return;
            }
    
            $chosen_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    
            if( ! is_array( $chosen_method ) ){
                return;
            }
    
            $chosen_method = $chosen_method[0];

            // Do something with the chosen method.
    
        }

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_detect_chosen_shipping_method', 10, 2 );
```

However, this wouldn't work for me because I needed to fire some javascript based on the selected shipping method. Here's how I accomplished it using some JavaScript that is present only on the checkout page:

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $( document ).ready( function(){

        $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', () =>{

            let prefixShippingMethods = document.querySelectorAll('#shipping_method .shipping_method');

            for (const prefixShippingMethod of prefixShippingMethods ){

                // We have to check for the hidden type as well because if only one shipping method is available WC doesn't show radio buttons.
                if( lpacShippingMethod.checked || lpacShippingMethod.type === 'hidden' ){
                    // Do something now that you know which method is checked
                    // NOTE! The shipping method name will not be exact, you will have to use indexOf() for comparisons

                    if( prefixShippingMethod.value.indexOf('local_pickup') ){
                        //This will happen when Local Pickup is selected
                    }
                    
                }

            }


        });

    });

})( jQuery );
```

You can clean up JS as you wish, I couldn't detect this event in vanilla JS, thats why I'm using jQuery here.